# Workaround for webpack require.context() using dynamic directories in Vue App

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, vue-router, webpack-4

I have a Vue app, and it contains a route with multiple image galleries. A user can click on one of these galleries to be taken to a dynamic component that will display the images that belong to the specific gallery they're looking at.

For example, the user sees 2 cards, `foo` and `bar`. Clicking on them will take the user to `/gallery/foo` or `/gallery/bar`. My assets folder is organized like this

```
src/assets/images
├── foo
│   └── 1.jpg
└── bar
    └── 2.jpg
```

So every gallery has a corresponding folder with all the images in it. I have no access to any kind of DB or APIs here, this project is basically a static website and calling any kind of external resource is outside the scope of this project.

I tried using Webpack's `require.context()` here, but it doesn't work with a dynamic path like I'm trying to do, as can be seen in [Webpack Issue #4772](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/4772).

The relevant code that I tried

```js
data() {
  return {
    images: null
  }
),
mounted() {
    this.populatePage();
  }
},
methods: {
  populatePage() {
    const imagePath = `@/assets/images/${this.$route.params.id}/`;
    this.images = this.importAll(require.context(imagePath, true, /\.(jpe?g)$/));
  },
  importAll(r) {
     return r.keys().map(r);
  }
}
```

This obviously doesn't work as demonstrated in the Github issue due to me using the `imagePath` in my `require.context()`. If I just do `@/assets/images/`, it works fine, but the problem is that it will import every single `jpg` in the images directory, which is obviously not what I want.

What's the best way to get the desired effect needed here? Preferably I'd want to avoid loading any images that don't belong to the page the user is on, as there can potentially be hundreds of them, and even though they're optimized as much as possible, they can still be quite large (~150kb each as these have to be a very high resolution)

Initially I tried doing some variation of just importing everything and then maybe regexing the folder name from the chunk that webpack generates, but webpack will ommit the directory and add a different hash to the end of the filename instead. Is there perhaps a way to make webpack append a directory to a filename in Vue, or really in general?

```sh
/img/1.2f159e72.jpg
/img/2.2c1da0da.jpg
```

Comment: can you provide sample code in `codesandbox` ?

Comment: What's the return of `${this.$route.params.id}` ?

Comment: @tuhin47 I'll do so once I'm back at my computer


@ThRnk That is a Vue Router variable that will return the `id` param of the current route. For example being on the `gallery/foo` page, `this.$route.params.id` returns `foo`

Comment: May I ask what's the reason that you are using assets directory instead of public directory? See https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/html-and-static-assets.html#when-to-use-the-public-folder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Webpack is highly configurable. You can set it up to retain directory structure - see [file-loader documentation](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/file-loader/#name)

`webpack.config.js`

```js
module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif)$/i,
        loader: 'file-loader',
        options: {
          name: '[path][name].[ext]',
        },
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

Then you can easily use your original approach importing whole root dir (with gallery directories) and filter only files from the gallery you want. Don't be afraid of importing everything - `file-loader` doesn't "load" the file over the wire, it just returns URL of the file (during the build). In order to load the file to the browser, you need to use it inside the `img` tag (for example)